# Display JSON array in Vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js, coldfusion, format, fw1

I'm getting this data from the Coldfusion Framework/1 API in JSON format:

```
{
  "COLUMNS": [
    "PRODUCT_ID",
    "PRODUCT_NAME",
    "PRODUCT_STATUS",
    "DT_CREATED"
  ],
  "DATA": [
    [
      102,
      "Window",
      "In Production",
      "November, 02 2018 10:33:13"
    ],
    [
      105,
      "Window",
      "Delivered",
      "November, 11 2018 15:00:00"
    ],
    ETC...
  ]
}
```

In developer tools, using Vue tool, I got this:

- data

  - errored: false
  - loading: true
  - windows: Object

    - COLUMNS: Array[4]
    - DATA: Array[22]

I'm using axios

```
new Vue({
    el: '#windows-list-data',
    data() {
      return {
      windows: null,
      loading: true,
      errored: false
    }
 },
mounted() {
  axios
    .get('https://my-server.local/index.cfm?action=api.get')
    .then( response => {
      this.windows = response.data

     })
    .catch( error =>  {
      console.log(error) 
      this.errored = true
    })
    .finally( () => this.loading = false )
}
```

Can someone tell me how to render the data in Vuejs in a view?
thanks

Comment: Out of topic, but you should consider Vuex actions for asynchronous tasks!

Comment: serializeJSON( queryData, "struct" ); returns an array of structs instead of the query notation. This might make it easier to loop over in vue.js. As far as I know, FW/1 does not support this parameter, so you have to do it yourself by not using fw.renderData( "json", .....).

Comment: You need to `JSON.parse(response.data)`, otherwise it's just a string.

Comment: Thank you all. This was very helpful

Comment: You should write up an answer if that was the solution to your problem. This will help others in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems should change

```js
this.windows = response.data
```

to

```js
let respDataStr = response.data
let jsObject = JSON.parse(respDataStr)
this.windows = jsObject
```